# Why should I use ember js

Tags: ember.js

I just became familiar with ember js and came to know that I have to build ember app and deploy the dist folder to my server. As I join new job and they were already using ember so I have to use it but I figured out some thing very bad. I wanted to share and ask for clarification.

1. It creates one large js file which was near 2MB and will increase as modules usage and features will increase.
2. As it is compiled to one file I cannot figure out which feature was broken and I have to look at it in the latest release or some thing like that.
3. While developing when I run the ember server it kills me when it is taking time.

Please let me know if you know some good points about ember also the bad points.

Answer (score 3):

Before this question gets closed, let me slip in some thoughts:

> It creates one large js file which was near 2MB and will increase as modules usage and features will increase.

Yes, it does. Basically, Ember is **large**. People have been exploring approaches to this for years, but AFAIK there is no silver bullet at the moment.

> As it is compiled to one file I cannot figure out which feature was broken and I have to look at it in the latest release or some thing like that.

I don't understand this part of your question. Perhaps you could provide details on a specific case.

> While developing when I run the ember server it kills me when it is taking time.

It's most likely the build process, not the server, which is slow. There are some approaches to solving this, including running the Windows console in administrator mode, which you can find by googling for "ember build slow". Here's a possibly out-of-date [SO question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712294/why-the-ember-cli-is-so-slow). The simplest approach is to get a faster machine with SSD, and/or work on Mac/Linux.

> Please let me know if you know some good points about ember also the bad points.

Many people love Ember. Many people hate it. Many people have a love-hate relationship with it. It appears that the current Ember adoption rate is in the low-to-mid single digits. Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: As it is compiled to one file I cannot figure out which feature was broken and I have to look at it in the latest release or some thing like that. From this part I mean say I had 20 features in a release everyone did their work, QAed, and published to server now with the new release some problem came because of one of the features. As it is one file js no body know which feature broke the whole thing.

Comment: If you really really have to, you *could* deliver source maps to production. But this is a general problem with minification. However I think if you have errors on production, you've done something wrong far earlier. Use the development build for debugging! Really! Also ember *is* large, but not [that large](http://iao.fi/ember-size/). 2MB seems like a lot, thats not only ember. Also more interested is the gzipped size, and that could easily be around 300KB. Thats large, but not larger then an image.